# VBA - Extracting values by tag attribute

Tags: html, excel, vba, tags

I have been using the following code to pull values from a web page.

```
Private Sub Update()

  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
  IE.Visible = False
  IE.navigate "cisco.com/" & Range("srNum").Value
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
  Set Doc = IE.document
  Dim sTag As String
  sTag = Doc.getElementById("caseheader").innerText

  Sheets.Add
  ActiveCell.Value = sTag

End Sub
```

I am now on a new page where I need to pull the value by the attribute "title". In the example below I need to find the attribute "title" with the value of "Priority" and then return the value of "P3".

```html
<div class="con-LFloat con-RAlign con-Priority Width25">
  <span class="con-text-bold Width20 con-RAlign">Priority :</span>
  <span class="con-text-bold con-LMargin5" title="Priority">P3</span>
</div>
```

I have tried using .item(0) or .Children(0) with no luck and I haven't found any documentation to walk me through it.

I need some assistance with this one or a site that can help me set it up.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
Dim htmlEle1 as IHTMLElement

On Error Resume Next
For Each htmlEle1 in Doc.All
    If htmlEle1.getAttribute("title") = "Priority" then Debug.Print htmlEle1.innertext   
Next htmlEle1
On Error GoTo 0
```

Also change `IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` to `IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False`

Comment: Thanks Ryszard. I haven't got this working just yet but still working on it.